# Problem with re rendering after updating object in array in state with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I am trying to add a user live indicator on images that are in a loaded into a react-native-snap-carousel . I have working although when I update the data array with just one element (online status) it renders everything, making it all go off and reload.

I am using socket.IO to send the message to update and that all works fine. I do not want to add all the code for different parts but can add if required.

I thought the point of react was it only re renders parts of the DOM that are changed. I know essentially the whole state has been copied, ammended and saved, it only has one thing changed. I want it just to update that one thing not reload everything.

My code works like this:-

TrendingMovies.js

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-native-snap-carousel";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default function TrendingMovies({ data }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  
  const handleClick = (item) => {
    console.log("Clicked");
  };
  return (
    <View className="mb-8 mt-20">
      <Text className="text-white text-xl mx-4 mb-5">Trending</Text>
      <Carousel
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <MovieCard handleClick={handleClick} item={item} />
        )}
        firstItem={1}
        // loop={true}
        inactiveSlideScale={0.85}
        inactiveSlideOpacity={0.7}
        sliderWidth={width}
        itemWidth={width * 0.42}
        slideStyle={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
      />

    </View>
  );
}

const MovieCard = ({ item, handleClick }) => {

  const filledStars = Math.floor(item.rating / 2);
  const maxStars = Array(5 - filledStars).fill('staro');
  const r = [...Array(filledStars).fill('star'), ...maxStars];

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleClick(item)}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: 'https://{my_site}/users/'+item.userID+'/profile.jpg' }}
        style={{
          width: width * 0.4,
          height: height * 0.2,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: "#fff",
        }}
        className="rounded-3xl"
      />
      <Text style={{color:'white'}}>{item.status}</Text>
            <View style={styles.rating}>

      {r.map((type, index) => {
        return <AntDesign key={index} name={type} size={20} color="yellow" />;
      })}
    </View>

    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ratingNumber: { marginRight: 0, fontFamily: 'Menlo', fontSize: 0 },
  rating: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginVertical: 4
  },
});
```

It is imported like and used like so :-

```
import TrendingMovies from "../components/trendingMovies";

const [trending, setTrending] = useState([]);

API CALL TO GET DATA
```

When it receives data from Socket.io to update,

```
const updateStatus = (data) => {

    const new_data = trending.map(userID => {
      if (userID === data.userID) {
        // No change
        return userID;
      } else {
        // Return a new circle 50px below
        return {
          ...userID,
          status: data.new_status,
        };
      }
    });
    // Re-render with the new array
    setTrending(new_data);

    }
```

How do I stop it from reloading everything, just change that one part that is the online status? At the minute it looks like a normal page fully reloading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

React uses the `key` prop to know which elements to re-render.  Right now, none of the MovieCards have keys, so when the list gets updated, React assumes every element is new.

Giving each MovieCard a key should solve your issue:

```js
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <MovieCard
            handleClick={handleClick}
            item={item}
            key={item.id}
          />
        )}
```

Make sure the key is unique.  See https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys for more.

Comment: makes sense mate, will try and let you know, cheer